# No data shown when using correct query

Tags: php, mysql

I got a small for each loop that I want to test. But it only shows me two empty list items. I also tested the SQL in phpmyadmin and it returns a correct table. I want to show the title from that table but like I said, I am getting two empty list items.

Does anybody know what I am doing wrong?

```
<?
    //  content
    $content            = "SELECT * FROM `snm_content` WHERE catid = 13";
    $contentcon         = $conn->query($content);
    $contentcr          = array();
    while ($contentcr[] = $contentcon->fetch_array());


    foreach($contentcr as $content) 
    {
        $contentje .= '<li>'.$contentcr['title'].'</li>';
    }
    echo $contentje;
?>
```

Comment: use [print_r](http://php.net/manual/de/function.print-r.php) function to find out what the content of the array is.

Comment: Does `$contentcr` contain what you want ?

Comment: Can you show a `print_r` or `var_dump` of this variable ?

Comment: @Heru-Luin Yes here is a screenshot: https://i.gyazo.com/75561aed219a77d1953d192eda95f04b.png

Comment: Can you make it a little more eye-friendly ? I just woke up :)

Comment: @Heru-Luin I don't know how? :P The title part is in the top, array item number 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `$contentcr` by `$content` inside the foreach loop.

```
<?
    //  content
    $content            = "SELECT * FROM `snm_content` WHERE catid = 13";
    $contentcon         = $conn->query($content);
    $contentcr          = array();
    while ($contentcr[] = $contentcon->fetch_array());


    foreach($contentcr as $content) 
    {
        $contentje .= '<li>'.$content['title'].'</li>'; // Here
    }
    echo $contentje;
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
while ($contentcr = $contentcon->fetch_array()) {

     $contentje .= '<li>'.$contentcr['title'].'</li>';
}
echo $contentje;
```

Comment: The while loop is not inside the other while loop.Or did you forget a bracket?

Comment: I got no output at all now. Not even the list item.

Comment: Yeah I did,but now I don't have any output.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `foreach` use only `while`

```
while ($contentcr = $contentcon->fetch_array());{
$contentje .= '<li>'.$contentcr['title'].'</li>';
}
```

Comment: This shows me only 1 empty list item. But the foreach is not in the while loop, it's under it, outside the while loop tags.

Comment: run this query **SELECT * FROM `snm_content` WHERE catid = 13** in phpmyadmin and check **title** value @twan

Comment: I did. And the title is correct there. Here a screenshot: https://i.gyazo.com/58b5d3e8a18fc57f2600fecd30cd0e6c.png

Comment: print_r($contentcr); inside while @twan

Comment: inside the while loop it prints nothing.